# replace arabic charset with hashtag preg_replace?

Tags: preg-replace, hashtag

I've made my own PHP script and my problem with `hashtags`

and I've added `preg_replace` function to replace tags to `hashtags` its working well when i use English charsets but in Arabic or any other language its not working

where is the problem in my code ?

```
$post = @preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w+)/', '<a class=\"hashtag\" href="hashtag.php?tag=\2">\1#\2</a>', $post);
```

i want `preg_repalce` to replace none english tags too how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found it

this is how to match arabic hastags

```
$post = @preg_replace('/(#\w+)/u', '<a class="hashtag" href="hashtag.php?tag=\1">\1</a>', $post);
```